# Horizontally Shift Certain Items in a Quote Environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, lists, quotation

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{quote}
\item \lipsum[3]
{\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item \lipsum[3]}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I am trying to horizontally shift the second item entirely `15pt` to the right; however, the command `{\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item \lipsum[3]}` only effects a 15pt indentation of the first line (which, I suppose, is what I asked for in the code.)

QUESTION: How may I horizontally shift the second item, say, 15pt to the right, so that the second block of text (which is identical to the first) lies underneath the first block, but shifted 15pt to the right? It seems like there should be a simple way to do this, but I haven't found it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a list environment such as `quote`, every paragraph is typeset with

```
\parshape1 \@totallleftmargin \linewidth
```

You can locally modify the setting:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{shiftquote}[1]{%
  \par
  \advance\@totalleftmargin#1\relax
  %\advance\linewidth -#1\relax % uncomment for keeping the right margin
  \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
}{\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{shiftquote}{15pt}
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\lipsum[3][4-7]
\end{shiftquote}

\lipsum[3]
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this; but I am looking, if possible, to shift the quote , say 15pt, past the righthand boundary as currently shown. I was hoping that this would be possible since the quote environment has margins on both sides and 15pt should not exceed the textwidth.

Comment: @mlchristians Changed the code (commenting out a line was enough).

Comment: @M.Logic No diphthong: [gre'gɔrio]

Comment: @M.Logic It's how I wrote before, in Italian. How an English speaker approximates the pronunciation is not my concern.

Comment: Many thanks egreg.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `quoting` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{quoting}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{quoting}[indentfirst=false,leftmargin=15pt,rightmargin=15pt]
  \lipsum[3]

  \begin{quoting}[indentfirst=false,leftmargin=15pt,rightmargin=-15pt]
    \lipsum[3]
  \end{quoting}
\end{quoting}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: +1 Many thanks for this helpful alternative approach.